# Trouble accessing another function in the same class (Python)

Tags: python

I'm a bit fresh with Python (doing usually C# stuff)..
I am trying to use another function that was defined in the same class and for some reason I cannot access it.

```
class runSelenium:

    def printTest():
        print('This works')

    def isElementPresent(locator):
        try:
            elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
            bRes = True
        except AssertionError:
            print('whatever')
        else:
            return False

    def selenium():
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("https://somesite.com/")
        printTest()
        isPresent = isElementPresent("//li[@class='someitem'][60]")
```

When trying to use printTest() and isElementPresent() I get: function not defined..
This is probably something ultra trivial I don't understand in Python..
Thanks for help!

Comment: the indentation in your example needs to be fixed.

Comment: In what way? I don't see any error on IDE regarding identation

Comment: Python relies on indentation. The functions should be indented to be part of the class. Also, all functions in a class need `self` as the first parameter. To call another function in the class, do `self.` first.

Comment: If the functions are supposed to be in the `class` indent the whole thing. Indentation is part of the syntax in python, it's not for decoration.

Comment: whatever methods you intend to be part of the class, need to be tabbed in below the class, what's currently displayed shows the fn defs at the same indentation level as the class def

Comment: Take a look at section 9.3.2 - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: is your `driver` variable declared anywhere else? Looks like it's local to `selenium()` to me.

Comment: If you want to write a class that does nothing use the `pass` statement. Even if you indent the functions they won't be instance attributes anyway. They will be executed as random statements while the class definition is being compiled.

Comment: All the functions are properly indented in the IDE. How do I use "self" or "pass" properly in my case?

Comment: Which Python 2 or 3 are you using ?

Comment: The problem isn't in your IDE, it's in the formatting of your post. We can't see your IDE, we only have what you wrote to go on, and what you wrote is broken. pro tip: after posting, copy the text from the website and paste it into a new file and try to run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few examples in python that should get you started:

```
class RunSelenium(object):

    def printTest(self):
        print('printTest 1!')

    @staticmethod
    def printTest2():
        print('printTest 2!')


def printTest3():
    print('printTest 3!')


# Call a method from an instantiated class
RunSelenium().printTest()

# Call a static method
RunSelenium.printTest2()

# Call a simple function
printTest3()
```

Answer (score 1):

**In case you are using Python2.X**

In your code every thing is interpreted sequentially not like a class, therefore, it cannot find the methods till they are defined.  You have several mistakes here:

1. Indentation of methods is incorrect, class will be in level 0,
   methods will have level 1( 1 tab)..
2. Class methods should have keyword `self` as a first parameters.
   For class fields use `self.field_name`
3. When you call a class method use `self.method_name()`

The code should be

```
class runSelenium:

    def printTest(self):
        print('This works')

    def isElementPresent(self,locator):
        try:
            elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
            bRes = True
        except AssertionError:
            print('whatever')
        else:
            return False

    def selenium(self):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("https://somesite.com/")
        self.printTest()
        isPresent = self.isElementPresent("//li[@class='someitem'][60]")

 #Edit: To Run
 a=runSelenium()
 a.selenium()
```

Comment: Ok, so now if I want to run runSelenium as my main function, how do I do that? runSelenium.selenium() doesn't seem to work and it asks for another parameter. Tried passing "self" to it but it fails

Comment: ok that will go into some kind of main function/area .. so first you need an object of type 'runSelenium' and then invoke 'selenium()'  ...  'a=runSelenium()' , then 'a.selenium()'

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohammed! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to call a function in the same class:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

class runSelenium:
    def __init__(self):
        # define a class attribute
        self.driver = None

    def printTest(self):
        print('This works')

    def isElementPresent(self, locator):
        try:
            elem = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
            bRes = True
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print('whatever')
        else:
            return False

    def selenium(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://somesite.com/")
        self.printTest()
        isPresent = self.isElementPresent("//li[@class='someitem'][60]")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create an instance of class runSelenium
    run = runSelenium()
    # call function
    run.selenium()
```

Comment: Thanks for help! If I declare the webdriver in the __init__ function how can I make sure it's still accessible to me in the other functions in the class?

Comment: It's a class attribute, so you can access it this way: `self.driver`

Answer (score 0):

Indent your functions. As of now, they aren't part of your class.

```
class runSelenium:

    def printTest():
        print('This works')

    def isElementPresent(locator):
        try:
            elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(locator)
            bRes = True
        except AssertionError:
            print('whatever')
        else:
            return False

    def selenium():
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get("https://somesite.com/")
        printTest()
        isPresent = isElementPresent("//li[@class='someitem'][60]")
```

You aren't getting any IDE syntax errors because those functions don't *have* to belong to the class. But they must be indented under the class to be part of the class.